Зеркало сайта/скраппинг
Задача сделать зеркало сложного сайта. Полностью копируя его верстку и функционал. Но только на моем домене. (доступа к файлам сайта не имею). Т.е пользователи моего сайта авторизуясь на моем сайте, через мою учетку будут заходить на сайт с которого буду копировать данные. Я пробую использовать selenium, но проблемы с отображением стилей. Подскажите какую лучше использовать библиотеку для такой задачи? Или как исправить отображение стилей с сайта.
Вот пример кода.
from flask import render_template
from app import app
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--headless')
#options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
#options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://mpstats.ru")
time.sleep(10)
main_page = driver.page_source

#main_page = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'html')


#m1 = main_page.get_attribute('innerHTML')


#app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html",title = 'Home')
@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    return main_page

